# Passing different methods as arguments in Java 8

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8, arguments

I've been looking in to lambda expressions and how to pass methods as arguments in java 8, but I'm not sure if its possible in my case:

I have multiple classes with similar methods, but the method name is different in some classes. Each method take a Long as a argument that represents ID.
So, I'm trying to make:

```
void setScore(List<Long> nodes, method){
    for (Long id : nodes)
        System.out.println( method(id) );
    }
}
```

This is two examples of methods I want to pass, but I have:

```
Double DegreeScorer<Long>.getVertexScore(Long id)
Double BetweennessCentrality<Long, Long>.getVertexRankScore(Long id)
```

I thought I had found a solution using LongConsumer Interface, but LongConsumer does not return any value so I cant store the results.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:**
I ended up with:

```
<T> void setScore(List<Long> nodes, LongFunction<T> getScore){
    for (Long id : nodes)
        System.out.println(getScore.apply(id));
    }
}

setScore(nodes, ranker::setVertexScore);
```

Comment: What about `LongToDoubleFunction`?

Comment: What about LongFunction<R> ? R is the return type.

Comment: how do you pass the function as a argument? My classes stores the results of an algorithm, so I want to call ranker.evaluate() first and then pass ranker.getVertexScore(Long id). What syntax do I use when calling setScore? setScore(nodes, ranker.getVertexScore) gives me an error

Comment: You can (probably) call it with `setScore(nodes, l -> ranker.getVertexScore(l))` or `setScore(nodes, ranker::getVertexScore)`. Please read the lambda tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html for more info

Answer (score 4):

If all your methods return a `Double` use a `java.util.Function<Long,Double>`:

```
void setScore(List<Long> nodes, Function<Long,Double> fn) {
    for (Long id : nodes)
         System.out.println(fn.apply(id));
    }
}
```

If you have different return types add a generic type parameter

```
<T> void setScore(List<Long> nodes, Function<Long,T> fn) {
    for (Long id : nodes)
         System.out.println(fn.apply(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: The type parameter `<T>` is obsolete. The method can accept a `Function<Long,?>` without any difference to the outcome.

Comment: @Holger you are right, the example does not depend on it. But in general there could be use cases  where you want a type parameter and not only the `?`